# tkinter text-aligning lots of text

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

How can I left text-align a large section of text in tkinter python?

I've tried anchor and sticky, but to no avail.

Here's my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

lots_of_text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing \
elit. Donec a rhoncus elit, ac mattis quam. Vestibulum ex enim, dictum \
vitae finibus sed, pharetra ac tellus. Integer in mollis lectus. \n\
ipsum nunc, venenatis sit amet augue mattis, faucibus blandit est. \
Vestibulum vel porta lorem. Quisque pretium sodales velit, non molestie \
rhoncus sed. Integer mattis eros nec porttitor auctor. \n\ 
Vivamus porta faucibus mi ac interdum. Morbi lobortis ipsum venenatis, \
fringilla justo vitae, dignissim elit."

root = tk.Tk()
info = tk.Label(root, text=lots_of_text)
info.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the key word argument `justify='left'`:
You also may use triple quotes for multi lines sentences.

```
import tkinter as tk

lots_of_text = """Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing \
elit. Donec a rhoncus elit, ac mattis quam. Vestibulum ex enim, dictum \
vitae finibus sed, pharetra ac tellus. Integer in mollis lectus. \n\
ipsum nunc, venenatis sit amet augue mattis, faucibus blandit est. \
Vestibulum vel porta lorem. Quisque pretium sodales velit, non molestie \
rhoncus sed. Integer mattis eros nec porttitor auctor. \n\ 
Vivamus porta faucibus mi ac interdum. Morbi lobortis ipsum venenatis, \
fringilla justo vitae, dignissim elit."""

root = tk.Tk()
info = tk.Label(root, text=lots_of_text, justify='left')
info.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

#### alternatively:

```
import tkinter as tk

lots_of_text = """Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
elit. Donec a rhoncus elit, ac mattis quam. Vestibulum ex enim, dictum
vitae finibus sed, pharetra ac tellus. Integer in mollis lectus.\n
ipsum nunc, venenatis sit amet augue mattis, faucibus blandit est.
Vestibulum vel porta lorem. Quisque pretium sodales velit, non molestie
rhoncus sed. Integer mattis eros nec porttitor auctor.
Vivamus porta faucibus mi ac interdum. Morbi lobortis ipsum venenatis,
fringilla justo vitae, dignissim elit."""

root = tk.Tk()
info = tk.Label(root, text=lots_of_text, justify='left')
info.pack()

root.mainloop()
```